# hosting the database on a remote server while developing

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if it's possible to host my database on a remote server and still run the application on my local machine while I'm developing it.

I'm using asp.net.

Thanks.

Comment: ok, cool; I realize that I should have added to the question. How do you do it? And is it a good/bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, rather than using `.` or the name of your machine as the server, just put in the IP address.

So if you're just using a connection string

```
Data Source=yourRemoteServer;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: One more thing: can SQL Management Studio also connect to a remote DB?

Comment: @frenchie, yes it does. Same thing, just give it the server address and the login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad the post with the reference to "SO is not your personal research assistant is gone" lol. It is pretty involved! You are first going to have to decide where to host the database, then register a new account with them, create the database, setup your schema or manage to use their janky import functionality, gather the connection string from their service, go to your web.config file and update your connection string to reflect their connection string, and vuala.

Comment: Actually, I already have all that setup. I was wondering if I could use the remote DB with my local machine.

Comment: @frenchie - as long as you have the permission to access the remote DB then all you need to change is the connection string assuming everything else is correct.

Comment: Yes, now I know. One more thing: is it possible to have SQL Management Studio access a remote DB?

Comment: @frenchie - You may want to pose that as a separate SO question, I am not very familiar with the SQL Management Studio.